# How to output True/False if attribute is a number in QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a points shapefile which has two fields that I want to use to determine the size of each point. One field, "StepYear", refers to the year of step change in a particular time series, and it contains both numbers (e.g. 1996), and non-numericals (such as NA or - ). The non-numericals indicate a number of different cases in which the test did not proceed.

If the test did not proceed, then I want the size of the point to be equal to 2. Otherwise, I want the size to be determined by the statistical significance of the test. I want code similar to the following:

```
CASE
  WHEN  NOT ISNUMBER("StepYear") THEN 1 
  WHEN  "StepSig" <= 0.01 THEN 8
  WHEN  "StepSig"  <= 0.05 THEN 6
  WHEN  "StepSig"  <= 0.1 THEN 4
  ELSE 2
END
```

However, I haven't been able to find any function that performs the "ISNUMBER" check. **Is there a function in the QGIS field calculator which outputs TRUE/FALSE for a numerical type check?**

Comment: I think the field type of "StepYear" is a string not integer, because you cannot put NA and - in number format like integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comment by @ahmadhanb, this is a workaround I would suggest:

```
CASE
WHEN  to_int(regexp_substr("StepYear", '(\\d+)')) IS NULL THEN 1 
WHEN  "StepSig" <= 0.01 THEN 8
WHEN  "StepSig" <= 0.05 THEN 6
WHEN  "StepSig" <= 0.1  THEN 4
ELSE  2
END
```

Above `to_int()` part will extract numbers from "StepYear" or return NULL. Please make sure the new field created by this expression is `integer` type.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a method for QGIS field calc other than ISNUMBER (which will work if you put your numbers into a number field instead of a string field), but in python you can use this syntax:

```
isinstance( <var>, ( int, long ) )
```

This will return true if the variable is a number.  However, like ahmadhanb said, your field is a string field and your integers are stored as strings.  If the number is stored as a string, isinstance will return FALSE, just like ISNUMBER is doing.

All you need to do to solve your problem is create a new number field and calc your numbers into this field.  The records without numbers should have blanks in this field after you do the calc.